# How do you search Google Docs by date?

Tags: google-drive, google-docs

I often need to search for documents by date (created or last modified) in Google Docs.
For example, forgetting where I put it (and the name/content), so needing to search *all* my Google Docs for files created yesterday, etc.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Google Drive accepts at least some of the same special search keywords as Gmail.

I searched for `before:2013-01-01 after:2012-12-15` and got back only files with "Lasted Edited" dates in that range.

Google support has more information about [searching your Google Drive](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375114), including the search operators it supports.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this fairly easily through All Items. You can even see the folder where it's saved.

1. Click **More** on the left
2. Click **All Items**
3. Choose to sort by **Last modified** or **Last edited by me** or **Last opened by me**

[image: google drive sort all files]

Comment: Not quite as fast, I think, as searching by date (if you're looking for a range of dates). But very useful info. Thanks!