# How (can?) you search the Google Trash for a particular folder that was deleted?

Tags: google-drive

A bug in Google Docs sync created a 16 GB duplicate folder on my desktop and when I deleted it it deleted the source fold (of which folder(1) was a duplicate).

So now I want (hopefully!) to restore that from the Trash.
BUT... when I got ot the trash it's trying to list 100,000 files before it gets to Projects.

Is there a way to quickly search for that Folder I deleted instead of waiting for Google Docs to crash my browser trying to load a list of 100,000 (16 GB worth) of files?

Comment: Do you know the folder name, what do you see when you do a search for that folder name?

Comment: I don't know all the names of the folders. And even those that I do: if I search on "folder name" it get "None of your Google Docs, files or folders matched this search."

Comment: If you know the name (or part of) you can simply search and there will be a link "one or more items in trash also matched your search". When you click on the link it will show you the items.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks.  I still need a way to find deleted folder for which I do not know the name, just roughly WHEN they were deleted.

Comment: Combine the solution above with the solution from http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/46026/10579 , e.g. first search for `before:2014/01/01 after:2012/12/15` then click the "several items in trash also matched your search" link. Does it work? I'll go ahead and post it as an answer if so.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

add `is:trashed  type:folder` to the search query

Comment: Why the downvote?
Also, this is the full search:  type:folder is:trashed